# How to sort a dictionary by its values if they are timedelta objects?

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary, key, timedelta

I have a python dictionary in which the keys are usernames in the form of strings and the values are in the form of `timedelta` objects. I need to sort the values in order from greatest to least and then access the keys so I can print the top ten values with their usernames in a file.

Once I sort the values using `sorted(dictionary.values())`, how do I access the usernames? I already tried `dictionary[datetime.timedelta(seconds=84081)]` but I get an attribute error: `datetime.datetime’ has no attribute ‘timedelta`. (FYI, I used: `from datetime import datetime, timedelta`.)

Comment: Use `sorted(dictionary.items(), key = lambda x: x[1])`

Comment: The quickest way to get answers here is often by searching to see if the question has already been asked.

Answer (score 0):

Simply using `dictionary.items()` to get key-pair value instead of only values `dictionary.values()`

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

dct = {
    'User1': timedelta(days = 12),
    'User2': timedelta(days = 232),
    'User3': timedelta(days = 152),
    'User4': timedelta(days = 323),
    'User5': timedelta(days = 172),
    'User6': timedelta(days = 312),
    'User7': timedelta(days = 512),
    'User8': timedelta(days = 192),
    'User9': timedelta(days = 612),
    'User10': timedelta(days = 172),
    'User11': timedelta(days = 912),
}

print(sorted(dct.items(), key= lambda x: x[1].days))
```

`x[0]` is key and `x[1]` is value (timedelta), you can simply remove `.days` because it has built-in comparison, but when coming up complex object, you have to specify which attribute is sorted key